# How to scan local directory using PHP script

Tags: php, localhost, drive

Here is my PHP script:

```
<?php
    $dir = 'R:/work/marketingProcess/BusinessMarketing/Design/Images/02_Product_Images/04_SHORT-RANGE\NINA/01_NINA-B1/source_WEB/';
    $files = scandir($dir);
    print_r($files);
?>
```

but I am finding warning:

> scandir(R:/work/marketingProcess/BusinessMarketing/Design/Images/02_Product_Images/04_SHORT-RANGE\NINA/01_NINA-B1/source_WEB/,R:/work/marketingProcess/BusinessMarketing/Design/Images/02_Product_Images/04_SHORT-RANGE\NINA/01_NINA-B1/source_WEB/):
> The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3) in
> C:\wamp64\www\network_drive\file.php on line 3

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: The error is telling you `The system cannot find the path specified` and your path is `R:/work/marketingProcess/BusinessMarketing/Design/Images/02_Product_Images/04_SHORT-RANGE\NINA/01_NINA-B1/source_WEB/,R:/work/marketingProcess/BusinessMarketing/Design/Images/02_Product_Images/04_SHORT-RANGE\NINA/01_NINA-B1/source_WEB/`

Comment: but i have a drive R and i am mentioning the path as well

Comment: ok, but your path doesnt seem to be valid... maybe this is causing the error? `...RANGE\NINA/01...`

Comment: Your path is not windows like. The part `E\NIN` is very baaaad.

Comment: how i can get the desire output please help

Comment: _please help..._ Did you read over my last comment and also @MarkusZeller comment?

Comment: Windows paths are like this: `$path = 'R:\\work\\images\\...'`; You are mixing *NIX (forward slashes) paths with Windows (backward slashes).